# vCloud SDK Filter on datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, sdk, vcloud-director-rest-api

## My Task:

I'm querying all tasks in my vCloud instance, this works correctly and as intended.
I figured i'd create filter to only get Todays tasks.

```
private static List<Filter> filter()
    {
        var filterList = new List<Filter>();

        filterList.Add(new Filter(new Expression(QueryTaskField.STARTDATE, DateTime.Today.ToString("s"), ExpressionType.GREATER_THAN)));

        return filterList;
    }
```

According to the documentation it should be able to use datetime fields.

## My Problem

When I run my code it returns "minorErrorCode="BAD_REQUEST" message="Bad request: Cannot parse '2014-10-29T00:00:00' as date."
I've tried numerous datetime formats and everything returns the same.

Any thoughts?

## Update:

## *Solution*

I found the solution -> trial and error...
The format needed to be ISO 8601 -> the "O" format, which includes timezone - mine looks like this `2014-10-29T00:00:00.0000000+01:00`
But apparently vmware didn't count on anyone living east of Greenwich, so I needed to convert the + to a -

and now it works

Comment: Which line you get this error? I don't see any parsing. Is it in `Expression` constructor?

Comment: Not in the filter, the filter isn't executed until i actually parse it, but that code isn't really needed to explain what I'm doing - problem is not with the code, but with the format.